# Counting odd numbers before a given number

Tags: python

I am doing a Kata problem in codewars, and I tried to figure it out by myself. The problem asks you to count the quantity of odd numbers there are before a number given. `Example: With number 7, function should return 3 because there are 3 odd numbers [1, 3, 5]; with number 13, function should return 6 - [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11].`

I have seen the possible results and I know it can be resolved with:

```
def oddnumber(n):

return (n // 2)
```

But the case is that I think my idea should work, but Im a beginner and want to understand what the problem is.

Thank you in advance. I tried this:

```
def odd_count(n):

    i==0

    conteo==0

    for i in int(n) - 1:

        if (i%2)==0:

            conteo+=0

        else:

            conteo+=1

    i+=1

    return conteo

print(odd_count(7))
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Curso Python Pildorasinformaticas\oddcount.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(odd_count(7))
  File "D:\Curso Python Pildorasinformaticas\oddcount.py", line 3, in odd_count
    i==0
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: `==` is for comparison. `=` is for assignment.`+=0` is unnecessary and you have indentation problems under your `if (i%2)==0:` statement.

Comment: Meawhile, `if i%2==1:x+=1` can be simplified to `x+=i%2`.

Comment: @Craig thanks, I've solved it

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using i as loop variable, however you have already assigned i as a variable before you use it in the loop.

You can also flip around your if statement just to include the case where the number is odd.

I created a quick and easy to understand solution that might help you out.

```
def count_odds(li,n):
    count = 0
    for i in (li):
        if i == n:
            break
        elif i % 2 != 0:
            count += 1
    return count

print(count_odds([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],7))
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally madre it. Do I have to close the question or something? I am new user of this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this:

```
def odd_count(n):

i=0

conteo=0

for i in range(n-1):

    if (i%2)!=0:

        conteo+=1   

i+=1

return conteo
```